# If statement with variable to be used in multiple places

Tags: if-statement, shiny, reactive

I am trying to build a shiny dashboard where i have to use an if statement to determine how a variable should be treated. in this case, the if statement assigns a multiple (either 1 or 0) which is then multiplied by multiple variables later in the code. I am unable to get an IF statement to work outside a renderUI function for some reason. I have tried to make it a reactive function but that did not work either.

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  LinerCost <- reactive ({ input$LLDPE_Liner/100 * DirectRM_Cost$Rs_KG[15] +
      input$Other_Additive_Liner/100 * DirectRM_Cost$Rs_KG[20]}) 

  reactive({if (input$lamination == "lam_yes") {
    lam_rm_multiple = 1} else {
      lam_rm_multiple = 0
    }}) 

  LamCost <- reactive({ LamCost * lam_rm_multiple })
  LinerCost <- reactive ({LinerCost * liner_rm_multiple})

  Weight <- reactive ({ 
    as.numeric(input$final_lam_weight) * lam_rm_multiple 
  }) 

  RMcost <- reactive({
    ((as.numeric(input$final_unlam_weight) / CombinedWeight()) * UnLamCost())
  }) 
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Here, I want the `lam_rm_multiple` to be assigned a value of either 0 or 1 and it is then multiplied to variables and force them to 0 as required. Currently, i get an error in shiny saying - Warning: Error in : object 'lam_rm_multiple' not found

Comment: Have a look at `?eventReactive`. Something like eventReactive({input$liner == "liner_yes"}, {...your code...}) should do it.

Comment: Thanks @ismirsehregal.. I ended up wrapping all the variables in as.numeric() and that worked for me.